# OSX clang++: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 for explicitely instantiated template in cpp file

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang++

I have template class defined in .h file and template methods are defined in .cpp file. This .cpp file also contains explicit template instantiation via `template clas Class<type>`.

This use case works correctly on VS2019 as same as on GCC (7.4.0). But, it's not working on OSX with clang++ (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 clang-1000.11.45.5).

Based on the documentation I believe this is a valid code. Is there any way how to make it work under OSX clang?

I don't want to move all implementations to .h because of better readability and because I need only two/three template instantiations.

Here are my test files:

`test.h`

```
#pragma once

template <class T>
class CTemplateTest
{
public:
  int Test();
};
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include "test.h"

template class CTemplateTest<int>;
template class CTemplateTest<double>;

template <class T>
int CTemplateTest<T>::Test()
{
    return 42;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    CTemplateTest<int> t1;
    CTemplateTest<double> t2;

    t1.Test();
    t2.Test();
}
```

`output`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CTemplateTest<double>::Test()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "CTemplateTest<int>::Test()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This could be because there is no such method called "TestAdd" that's defined in the template, or the shown code. In this case, I'd expect a different compilation error, though. The obvious conclusion is that the shown code is not the real code that's being compiled, as such anything that anyone could offer as a possible explanation is mere speculation, and a random guess. I am not sure I understand why, instead of showing the actual code that produces this compilation error, completely fake code is shown instead.

Comment: Sorry, TestAdd was original code I updated for the SO question. It's updated now (but I believe this wasn't so huge mistake! ;-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The member function was not instantiated. Which is no surprise, because you do the explicit instantiation *before* defining `CTemplateTest<T>::Test`. Move the explicit instantiation into the end of `test.cpp`

```
template <class T>
int CTemplateTest<T>::Test()
{
    return 42;
}

template class CTemplateTest<int>;
template class CTemplateTest<double>;
```

And I suggest you add an explicit instantiation declaration to the header

```
template <class T>
class CTemplateTest
{
public:
  int Test();
};

extern template class CTemplateTest<int>;
extern template class CTemplateTest<double>;
```

This instructs the compiler to forego much of the implicit instantiation, when the specific specializations are used. It will know the full definition is elsewhere.

Also, it serves a good documentation purpose. Now one can know the supported types by just reading the header.

Comment: You're right! I just figured it out too ;-). Thanks for info about header placement. It's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will answer my question.

For the reasons I don't understand clang++ needs these explicit instantiations AFTER all other code.

So, the correct form of the `test.cpp` file is:

```
#include "test.h"

template <class T>
int CTemplateTest<T>::Test()
{
    return 42;
}

template class CTemplateTest<int>;
template class CTemplateTest<double>;
```

I hope this help also someone else!